# Django FileField store Keras .h5 file

Tags: django, keras, hdf5, filefield

I am trying to store a trained Keras model within a Django model FileField. Since Keras is not pickleable, I used the .h5 file format (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize) to store the keras model. So basically just:

```
    kerasmodel.save('temp.h5')
    dat = open('temp.h5', mode='r')
    myFile = File(dat)
    mymodel.content.save('test', myFile)
```

mymodel.content is the  Django model FileField

This causes the error:

> UnicodeDecodeError at /model/
> 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 1928: character maps to "undefined"

I really don't care if Django can read this file or not, I just want to save it for later purposes. Since I can easily upload the file manually via the Django admin page to the model, it should be feasible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have u solve the case? Cause i want to to do the same thing